# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'keys' could not be found

Tags: angular, pipe

This is my first post, so I apologise if I am not following some rules.
The title of this post probably rings a bell as I've looked in all results around it but could not find the root cause of my problem.

I have a modal that opens to display a form in which I have a select that will list options from an enum. I am applying a pipe to this enum to make the object an array.

But I am getting the pipe 'keys' not found issue.

I highly appreciate your help!

So my **app.module.ts**

```
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WaitingTime, YearsAgo, SortBy, KeysPipe} from '../pipes/mypipe';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    WaitingTime,
    YearsAgo,
    SortBy,
    KeysPipe //declaring my pipe here
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    MyDateListService    
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

then my HomePage **home.ts** (will spare some unnecessary lines).
This is from where the modal will open.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController, AlertController, ItemSliding} from 
'ionic-angular';
import {DateFormPage} from '../date-form/date-form'
import {WaitingTime, YearsAgo} from '../../pipes/mypipe';
import {MyDates } from '../../models/my-dates';
import {MyDateListService} from '../../services/date-list'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {}
```

the modal page that opens **date-form.ts**
in which I need the pipe to function

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-
angular';
import {NgForm, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from 
'@angular/forms'
import { MyDateListService } from '../../services/date-list';
import {KeysPipe} from '../../pipes/mypipe'; //here is the pipe
import {DateTypes} from '../../models/enums';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-date-form',
  templateUrl: 'date-form.html'
})

export class DateFormPage implements OnInit {}
```

and finally my pipe **mypipe.ts**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

//declaring all my pipes
@Pipe ({
    name:'waitingTime'
})

export class WaitingTime implements PipeTransform
{   }
[.... all the other pipes]

// and this is the pipe that is not found.
@Pipe ({ 
    name: 'keys', 
    pure: false 
})

export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the WaitingTime pipe working fine? Also what page is the error coming from?

Comment: I don't see `DateFormPage` declared in the module.

Comment: @ZackSunderland Yes all the other pipes declared before are found and working fine (used in the HomePage.

Comment: @acdcjunior DateFormPage loads and works perfectly well (when not having the pipe in)
If you mean in app.module.ts ? Already tried that and it gives me this error : Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type DateFormPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and DateFormPageModule!

It is already imported in home.ts

Comment: @Jojo what exactly is the error, and what page is it coming from?

Comment: @Jojo If `DateFormPage` is declared at `DateFormPageModule`, then you need to declare the pipe at `DateFormPageModule`. Have you tried adding `KeysPipe` to `DateFormPageModule`?

Comment: @SimplyComplexable the error comes when the modal page date-form opens

Comment: acdcjunior, thanks for your feedback. DateFormPage is declared in home.ts by using import. I don't have a DateFormPageModule (if you mean having @ngModule in date-form.ts?).
I only have one module, the app.module.ts.
So are you saying I should add to my date-form.ts: 
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core' and then a @NgModule({declarations:[KeysPipe]}] ?
I assumed that by declaring in in my app.module.js it would be enough.

Comment: The complete error is the following:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally found my mistake, probably because still a bit of a rookie and did not notice the pages created automatically by ionic.

I was trying to get @NgModule in my **date-form.ts** when I already had a **date-form.module.t**s where my module is defined.
So declaring my pipe there, and removing its declaration from the other module **app.module.ts** made it work.

Thanks to all your comments, they they guided me to understand the source of my issue.